# Issue with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

[image]    var responsePromisecom = $http.get("restapi calling");
        responsePromisecom.success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.items=data.platform.record; 
        });
        responsePromisecom.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert("ajax failed");
        });
    };

I'm making a REST API call using `$http.get()`. I want to show the response data using `ng-repeat` in my page. When the data is an array (means if the response data contains more than one object) it works fine. But, when the response data contains only one record, `ng-repeat` does not work properly. I don't want to use `$watch`. Is there any way to do so? If the items return 1 record, `ng-repeat` repeats more than once without any data. If the items return 2 records `ng-repeat` works fine.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
  {{item.id}}
</div>
```

Comment: you need to share more of your code

Comment: please provide your data and assinged code and if possible provide a link of jsfiddle or plncr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for length of the array and do this,

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items ng-if="items.length > 1">
  {{item.id}}
</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in items[0]  ng-if="items.length == 1">
 {{item.id}}
</div>
```

**EDIT**

```
var responsePromisecom = $http.get("restapi calling");
    responsePromisecom.success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        if(data.platform.record.length == 1){
           $scope.items.push(data.platform.record); 
        }
        else
        {
           $scope.items = data.platform.record; 
        }           
    });
    responsePromisecom.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {  
        alert("ajax failed");
    });
};
```

Comment: my uib-accordion works fine in laptop. but when i access the page on phone the accordion are dont collapse

Comment: probably css could be the issue

Comment: are you refering to bootstrap?

Comment: im using ui-bootstrap also bootstrap3. is there any issue if i have a ng-click

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` is not the root cause, I guess that when you call rest api, when result just an item, it return an object not an array. So you need edit the code to return array when return an item.

Comment: how to achieve it

Comment: $scope.items= [];
angular.forEach($data.platform.record, function(element) {
  $scope.items.push(element);
});

Comment: can use explain more forEach function that you used.

Comment: it a loop in data.platform.record to push each item in $scope.items

Comment: im a newbie to angularjs .im worki ng with $http.get() and how can i do this in success function

Comment: why using $ in data.platform.record

Comment: bro can u edit the code.As im not getting data in view

Answer (score 0):

`ng-repeat` is working here with one element in array. check out here

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/l1tDK5T3jWpK3ksWSMFY?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

you have just to check response is object or array this may help you

```
 if(data.platform.record[0] == undefined){
    $scope.items=[data.platform.record]; 
}else{
    $scope.items=data.platform.record; 
}
```